# How to prevent a sliding div from displacing other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some **div** elements. All of them are supposed to slide in when the page is opened. Three of them are sliding in horizontally and one is sliding in vertically.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#lineHor1").toggle("slide");
            $("#lineHor2").toggle("slide");
            $("#lineHor3").toggle("slide");

            $("#lineVer1").slideToggle("slow");
        });
```

```css
        .lineSliderHor {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #000000;
            display: none;
        }

        .lineSliderVer {
            width: 2px;
            height: 1000px;
            background: #000000;
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lineVer1" class="lineSliderVer"></div>
    <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
    <div id="lineHor1" class="lineSliderHor"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="lineHor2" class="lineSliderHor"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="lineHor3" class="lineSliderHor"></div>
```

So my plan was to use this kind of behavior as animation on the page. As you can see the **div** sliding in vertically forces all other **div**'s down. I want all the lines to overlap. Is there a way to achieve this? Is it even reasonable to do it this way, or should I use a **canvas** for this kind of requirement?

Comment: If you add `position:absolute;` to `.lineSliderVer` in your css. Does that get in the vicinity of the goal?

Comment: @Me.Name Yes it does!

Comment: also css3 animations might help

Comment: @Me.Name write an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Okidoki, done, thought that you would have further requirements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to not have the vertical line push down the other elements, is to have its position absolute

```
        .lineSliderVer {
            ...
            position: absolute;
        }
```

Snippet

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#lineHor1").toggle("slide");
            $("#lineHor2").toggle("slide");
            $("#lineHor3").toggle("slide");

            $("#lineVer1").slideToggle("slow");
        });
```

```css
        .lineSliderHor {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 2px;
            background: #000000;
            display: none;
        }

        .lineSliderVer {
            width: 2px;
            height: 1000px;
            background: #000000;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lineVer1" class="lineSliderVer"></div>
    <p>Click anywhere to toggle the box.</p>
    <div id="lineHor1" class="lineSliderHor"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="lineHor2" class="lineSliderHor"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="lineHor3" class="lineSliderHor"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`position:absolute;`

But this may not behave as you want because this makes the div break out of its parents constraints. Unless you use:

```
position:relative;
```

On the parent div.

If you choose **position: absolute** I prefer to use  [JQuery.animate();](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) as you can reference CSS properties directly (such as left or marginRight) and easing for more customisable sliding.

I hope this achieves something you're looking for.